# Travis build timeouts even though test output reports success

Tags: python, travis-ci, httpretty

My Travis build is timing out for some reason. 
Here is the link to the logs: https://travis-ci.org/madedotcom/atomicpuppy/builds/70202335

And my current travis yml https://github.com/madedotcom/atomicpuppy/blob/master/.travis.yml

I have tried running it with a normal script command

```
script: run-contexts --verbose
```

As well as creating a bash script that ran the tests and exited with $?

```
script: ./run-tests.sh

# run-tests.sh
run-contexts --verbose ./tests 2>/dev/null
exit $?
```

Even this didn't help.

My best guess is that there is some task running in the background of my Travis build due to depending on asynchronous python libs, but how can I debug that on Travis? Is there any way to increase verbosity?

Worth adding that locally tests are very fast to run, and exit with 0 without any problems, using the same commands.

Comment: Hey Piotr, I did some tests by forking your repo and it seems the problem lies in the following test file: `tests/test_posting.py`. Indeed, when I renamed it so it is not executed your build passed and correctly finished. Maybe you could double-check your tests in the file to see what's wrong? Here is the the build report with the change that made the build succeed: https://travis-ci.org/cotsog/atomicpuppy/builds/70238803. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Dominic, thank you for your answer! I will take a closer look at this file. Could you please provide the steps you took to realize the problem was in this file? I'm still very confused on how to debug travis builds as I could not reproduce the problem locally. It will be really helpful and I will include it into my original post when I find the final solution.

Comment: I had a hunch the problem might be in your tests. Hence I renamed your test files one by one to see if I could make at least one test file run successfully. I had a successful build when `test_posting.py` was renamed/disabled. Then I renamed/re-enabled all the other test files except `test_posting.py` and I had another successful build. Then I concluded the problem was in that file. Kind of a brute force method. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Upgrade the version of [HTTPretty](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpretty).

Turns out there was a known issue with a library called HTTPretty ([issue can be found here](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/issues/228)) that caused the test runner to stall on travis without producing any errors.